# Hide Visualforce Chart Based on Number of Data Points

Tags: rendered, visualforce-charting

I want to hide a Visualforce Chart if there are no data points. Since PieData is a list of data points, why can I not use the style below?

```
<apex:page Controller="PieChartController" rendered="{!Piedata.size() > 0}">
```

Example chart from Salesforce Documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_overview_simple_example.htm

```
public class PieChartController {
public List<PieWedgeData> getPieData() {
    List<PieWedgeData> data = new List<PieWedgeData>();
    data.add(new PieWedgeData('Jan', 30));
    data.add(new PieWedgeData('Feb', 15));
    data.add(new PieWedgeData('Mar', 10));
    data.add(new PieWedgeData('Apr', 20));
    data.add(new PieWedgeData('May', 20));
    data.add(new PieWedgeData('Jun', 5));
    return data;
}

// Wrapper class
public class PieWedgeData {

    public String name { get; set; }
    public Integer data { get; set; }

    public PieWedgeData(String name, Integer data) {
        this.name = name;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax issue in your code, your condition will work if you make a small change.

```
<apex:page ... rendered="{!Piedata.size() > 0}">
```

This will not work as it is not a formula as required in VF page.

Change it to.  `<apex:page ... rendered="{!Piedata.size > 0}">`

You can also use `.empty` property as well `<apex:page ... rendered="{!Piedata.empty}">`.

Answer (score 1):

Change to `rendered="{!Piedata.size>0}"`